# Trouble with PyInstaller packaging specific files

Tags: python, directory, pyinstaller, packaging

PyInstaller not detecting --add-data directory commands

Hello everyone, I have a question regarding PyInstaller and the apparent ninth circle of hell I've opened trying to package a PyQT5 application into an executable.

So my application has multiple files that need to be externally added by command line for PyInstaller to package.

These files are

`data.json (D:\autolocke\autoLocke\autolocke\Data\data.json) style.qss (D:\autolocke\autoLocke\style.qss) fireredroutes.txt (D:\autolocke\autoLocke\autolocke\Data\fireredroutes.txt) NatDexPokemonG3.txt (D:\autolocke\autoLocke\autolocke\Data\NatDexPokemonG3.txt)`

The main .py script is
main.py (D:\autolocke\autoLocke\main.py)

Now I run the following command to add the four external files:

`pyinstaller --add-data "autolocke/Data/data.json;autolocke/Data" --add-data "autolocke/style.qss;autolocke" --add-data "autolocke/Data/fireredroutes.txt;autolocke/Data" main.py`

This works fine, except for the fireredroutes.txt. It fetches the style.qss and data.json.

Any help would be greatly appriciated, i can also provide the github repo if there is any confusion regarding the directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, for some reason, the final addition for the txt files needed to have the \ seperator instead of the / seperator, for example

```
pyinstaller --add-data "autolocke/Data/data.json;autolocke/Data" --add-data "autolocke/style.qss;autolocke" --add-data "autolocke\Data\fireredroutes.txt;autolocke\Data" main.py
```

this worked ^

```
pyinstaller --add-data "autolocke/Data/data.json;autolocke/Data" --add-data "autolocke/style.qss;autolocke" --add-data "autolocke/Data/fireredroutes.txt;autolocke/Data" main.py
```

this however did not.
Why? no idea